# Programming Assignment; Constructor -> Invalid Start of Expression + SemiColon Obsession

Tags: java, constructor, instance-variables

I am in an Introduction to Programming class for Roane State Community College. I have read the entire chapter 3 chapter, taken the quize, and passed.

So, now I am beyond frustrated after many hours of attempting to create an Employee class file with 3 different instance variables that will then be initialized by an Employee Constructor.

The three variables are as such:

1. first name (String type variable)
2. last name (String type variable)
3. monthly salary (double type floating variable)

The instructor provided us with some "signatures of the constructor and the methods for your reference:"

```
public Employee(String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
public void setFirstName( String fName )
public void setLastName( String lName )
public void setSalary(double empSalary )
public String getFirstName()
public String getLastName()
public double getSalary()
```

So, I have driven myself insane twice, and am once again at my wits end as I have manipulated my code, and replaced variables such as int with variations that I thought could possible yield a correct result, then changed them back, all the while consulting the Internet, threads on this site, and my textbook. Here's my code in its "Vanilla Format" before I've added any form of alternatives to its code:

/******************************************************
 File: 9-27.java
 Author: Steven Dorsey
 Date: Sept. 2014
 Description: This is an Employee Class File
******************************************************/

```
//Initiation the Class file first iirc
```

public class Employee
{
    int FirstName, LastName, Salary; //Instance variables

```
// main method begins program execution
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    // should introduce and initialize the constructor Employee
    public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
        Salary = empSalary;
    }
```

// Below: the set and get methods

```
    public void setFirstName( int fName ) // set the First Name
    {
        FirstName = fName;
    }

    public void setLastName( int lName ) // set the Last Name
    {
        LastName = lName;
    }

    public void setSalary( int empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
    {
        Salary = empSalary;
    }

    public int getFirstName() // get the First Name
    {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public int getLastName() // get the Last Name
    {
        return LastName;
    }

    public int getSalary() // get the Employee Salary
    {
        return Salary;
    }
} // End of Main
```

} // End of Class

(For some reason the last two lines here that close my Main and my Class file are not being included in the quotation and stuff, but you get the idea. )

Now, I believe I must first create the class Employee, and then create the Main in the Employee class file so that the Constructor can initialize the instance variables therein using the set and get commands.

What I believe should happen, is that a Command Prompt should show up and ask for first name, then retrieve it, and do so again for last name, and then salary.

However, my TextPad program does not make it past compiling thanks to the following errors being presented. These will be difficult to read unless you are forewarned there are about 14 errors, adn all start with a "> E:[DRIVE LOCATION] which is then followed with a Colon, error message, and the line of code in question with an upwards arrow pointing at the exact location, which is systematically moved by your block quotes, and there is no way for me to keep the upwards error symbol to show you where the issue occurs on every error. I've been going insane since 8:30 in the monring, and this website too is seeming to be giving me trouble with just trying to post a help message. :(

---

> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: ')' expected
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>                                  ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>                                        ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: ';' expected
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>                                                ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: not a statement
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>                                                 ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: ';' expected
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>                                                      ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:16: error: ';' expected
>           public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
>                                                                        ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
>           public void setFirstName( int fName ) // set the First Name
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
>           public void setFirstName( int fName ) // set the First Name
>                  ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:23: error: ';' expected
>           public void setFirstName( int fName ) // set the First Name
>                                   ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:23: error: ';' expected
>           public void setFirstName( int fName ) // set the First Name
>                                              ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:28: error: illegal start of expression
>           public void setLastName( int lName ) // set the Last Name
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:28: error: illegal start of expression
>           public void setLastName( int lName ) // set the Last Name
>                  ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:28: error: ';' expected
>           public void setLastName( int lName ) // set the Last Name
>                                  ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:28: error: ';' expected
>           public void setLastName( int lName ) // set the Last Name
>                                             ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:33: error: illegal start of expression
>           public void setSalary( int empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:33: error: illegal start of expression
>           public void setSalary( int empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
>                  ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:33: error: ';' expected
>           public void setSalary( int empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
>                                ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:33: error: ';' expected
>           public void setSalary( int empSalary ) // set the Employee Salary
>                                               ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
>           public int getFirstName() // get the First Name
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:38: error: ';' expected
>           public int getFirstName() // get the First Name
>                                  ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:43: error: illegal start of expression
>           public int getLastName() // get the Last Name
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:43: error: ';' expected
>           public int getLastName() // get the Last Name
>                                 ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:48: error: illegal start of expression
>           public int getSalary() // get the Employee Salary
>           ^
>
> E:\Libraries\School\Intro to Programming\Programming Assignment 2\Program 2\Employee.java:48: error: ';' expected
>           public int getSalary() // get the Employee Salary
>                               ^
>
> 25 errors
>
> Tool completed with exit code 1

---

Ultimately, the first error says public is not a valid start of expression for declaring the constructor, adn teh rest follow in declaring that I need parenthesis where parenthesis do not go, and semicolons where tehy do not go (after an instance variable, or int command, or whatever), and they all say how my exact code here requires some code that eimplies something unrelated to the parameters that follow a constructor, or the set/get command parameters. :\

Now, if I remove `public static void main( String[] args )` from the code entirely, and just declare a class file, then a constructor with the instance variables and commands, it will compile the Java file just fine. My only issue then, is that the Command Prompt will demand I include a main. And upon including a main, all 14-26 of those errors occur to everything relating to the constructor, instance variables, and commands.

I'm sure that I won't get this program done by tomorrow now. :(

Comment: put the constructor inside the Employee class but outside of main()

Comment: So, I just push Constructor back one indent, and it should work?

Comment: See http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-constructor-tutorial for examples of where to place the constructor, `main()`, and the other functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write a method INSIDE another method. Write all of your methods outside body of MAIN method

to make it more clear look at this

```
class Employee{
  String fname,lname;
  double salary;

  static void main()
  {/*body of main*/}

  public Employee()
  {/*body of constructor*/}

  void func1()
  {/*body of func1*/}
}//End of Class
```

Comment: Thanks. That has clarified a lot now. :) 
I have teh main above the Constructor but terminated before adding the constructor and all the following functions outside of Main as you have stated.

Comment: You are welcome. Also wherever you put main() (before or after constructor) it doesn't affect your program. Its not a rule to always put main() first then constructor and other functions.

Comment: Now my only issue remains that the TextPad program is emphatical that I can not convert "fName", "lName", or "empSalary" to Integer format, while having upwards arrows underneath each respective variable which point to the f, l, and e of each. Perhaps this has something to do with integers being of a different hierarchy fromm string type variables?

Comment: Check the edited code as you are not declaring attributes correctly in the class.

Comment: Yeah. :p I had to remove Int from the whole code, and declare the two String variables, then have a second line that declared the double variable for Salary on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a constructor in the main method it should declared as a method itself in the class as well as other methods including your accessor and mutator methods( get and set method) look at this code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    // should introduce and initialize the constructor Employee
    public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
        Salary = empSalary;
    }
```

This code should look like:

```
    public Employee( String fName, String lName, double empSalary )
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
        Salary = empSalary;
    }

public static void main( String[] args )
{
}
```

This goes for all other methods you create. You can't declare the methods you written in any other method you created. You can use objects to call your methods or if they are static methods you can use the class name to  call the methods. You should read up on creating creating objects of classes and using them to call methods. Hope this helps. You call the constructor usually when you create the method.

```
 Basically, all you have to do to make the program run is highlight all the methods in the main 
`class, then cut it, then paste it in the class 
but outside the main method` an your code should run properly.
```